# How to do Automatic Solr Backup?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am using solr 6 and tried to do the manual back up using the URL :

```
http://ipaddress:8983/solr/COLLECTION/replication?command=backup&location=/home/solrbackup/&name=SearchSolrBackUp
```

And i came to know for the automatic backup i need to do something like :

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" >
 <lst name="master">
  <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
  <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
  <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
  <str name="backupAfter">commit</str>
  <str name="maxNumberOfBackups">10</str>

 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

1. Is it the right approach to take the automatic backup?
2. If i am having 10 collections then hopefully i need to update this
   in 10 collections?
3. After every commit (index of documents to core) it starts taking
   backup and the maximum upto 10 backups i can take for that core ,but
   now the 11 one come ? what will happen the first one will go in
   drain or its getting deleted automatically?

Answer (score 0):

SolrCloud has its own replication handler, so it's usually a good idea to not change it or define a new one. Instead, use the [backup endpoint for the collections API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-BackupCollection).

I'm not sure about what you mean with "automatic backup", but in SolrCloud terms adding another replication node is done by upping the replicationFactor for a collection. If you'd define your own replication configuration, you'll have to manually manage where your nodes are and what shards they contain.

The backup command in the collections endpoint does this for you, by contacting each server and retrieving the shard located on the server.

Comment: Even i am not sure the link you provided as i already tried with that.The above link which i provided is working fine and i took the backup. But now i am getting confused with exploring the more into this.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Making+and+Restoring+Backups

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication#IndexReplication-ConfiguringtheReplicationHandler

Comment: If you're thinking about the max backups to keep-parameter, it will just remove the oldest backup when you reach that amount of backups. But you still have to call the backup command yourself. I'm not sure if the collections api support the same command, but remember that this actually fetches everything from your cluster, and not just for the local machine (where /replication lives) and creates a complete backup of your Solr state. Expire old backups by iterating over the backup directory instead externally from Solr.